# My javascript code is breaking when I add a an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a big problem with my code. Everything works like I want, but when I add an input that trigger a jQuery code everything break (the page load when it shouldn't and the code don't work) and I can't find a solution, i don't even know what is the cause because the console don't return any error. 
Here is the input:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" id="headline1" maxlength="30" style="width: 350px;float:left;min-height: 32px;">
<span id="countHeadline1" class="adCounter" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);float:left;position: inherit;margin-left: 0px;">0</span>
```

And here is the jQuery triggered:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  $('#headline1').keyup(updateCount);
  jQuery('#headline1').keydown(updateCount);

  function updateCount() {
    var cs = [jQuery(this).val().length];
    jQuery('#countHeadline1').text(cs);
    var cs = [jQuery(this).val()];
    jQuery('#headlineText').text(cs);
  }

  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
});
```

Any clue what is wrong?
Thank you,

Comment: Consider using indentation when writing code - it'll be much easier to read, and will make debugging less of a pain.

Comment: Why do you use both `$()` and `jQuery()`? Also, why do you declare the same variable  (`var cs`) twice?

Comment: you are using jquery or you want to do it with javascript?

Comment: Why do you put the length and value in arrays?

Comment: `color: rgb(255, 255, 255)` is white text. If the background is also white, you won't see it.

Comment: There's no `id="headlineText"` in your HTML.

Comment: Hi guys, changing $ to jQuery was because of a troubleshooting I've done, but that doesn't change the problem.

Comment: jQuery or Javascript, it doesn't matter

Comment: The color is  not the problem

Comment: The code looks indented in my browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** After an email conversation with the questioner, we determined that the root cause was a missing `</div>`. The code does work.

Your code works. ([click here](https://jsfiddle.net/nepaltechguy2/xpvt214o/359217/)) There must be some other bug. Below, I have made a couple improvements to your JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  $('#headline1').keyup(updateCount).keydown(updateCount);

  function updateCount() {
    var cs = $(this).val().length;
    $('#countHeadline1').text(cs);
    cs = $(this).val();
    $('#headlineText').text(cs);
  }

  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
});
```

Basically I replaced all the `jQuery`s with `$` and got rid of the second `var`. I also got rid of the secondary `#headline1` to clean up your code a bit.

Comment: Yeah the code works on fiddle, but not when used in my own code. Thank you for the improvements.

Comment: @Yagami can you give a bigger piece of code so we have more to work with? Ideally, this piece of code alone should cause the bug.

Comment: Is there a way we can chat or other ways to send you the code?

Comment: You can send an email to my spam -- samyok.nepal@outlook.com. I can reply to you there.

Comment: message sent. Thx